# How to calculate integer expression in Java

Tags: java, math, integer, floating-point

Suppose, I need to calculate `3 * (2 / 3) = 2` but `3 * (2 / 3) = 0` in integer arithmetic. So, it looks like I should use floating-point arithmetic `3 * (2.0 / 3) = 2.0` and *cast* the floating point result to `int`.

Does it make sense? How would you avoid casting here?

Comment: Can't you move the paranthesis like (3 * 2) / 3?

Answer (score 5):

In this particular example, you may be better off rearranging the expression as `3 * 2 / 3`, or as `3 / 3 * 2`. This way you'll get the exact result using integer math alone.

Using floating-point math is the more general solution, but you need to be aware of rounding issues. In general, you shouldn't expect that `x * (y / x)` would give you exactly `y` when `x` and `y` are floating-point numbers.

If you know that the result is an integer, or simply want to round it to the nearest integer, you could use [`Math.round()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28float%29):

```
Math.round(3 * (2f / 3))
```

Simply *casting* the result to `int` is not a good idea since floating-point numbers are inexact, and such a cast would simply *truncate* the number.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid casting. You can either use integer division or you can use full division but then arguments and result will be in floating point.
You can try moving around the expression parts to bring out the integer division to the top level. In your case you could transform `3 * (2 / 3)` to `(3 * 2) / 3` which will result in 2 without any floating point operations.

Answer (score 1):

`*` and `/` have the same precedence, so omitting the parentheses will provide you with a correct result of the example.

Casting (or truncating) is unavoidable otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would re-arrange the equation to be:

```
3 / 3 * 2 = 2
```

But not sure if thats what you need. You could try doing the calculation on float's and then use round() to round it up or down to the nearest integar.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the integer division. In these kinds of expressions you are better off using float, yes.

You can avoid the explicit casting only if you are using the compound operator. The compound operator does an automatic cast for you.

```
int a = 3;
a *= (2.0/3);
System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is it you want to achieve? Using integer arithmetic the result depends on where you set you parentheses. `(a/b) * (c/d) * (e/f)` will, as you noticed yourself, in general result in something different than `(a*c*d) / (b*d*f)`, even though mathematically both expressions are equal. Nontheless both expressions may be correct depending on the task you want to solve. I do miss a clear statement of this.

If you are looking for the integer closest to the mathematically correct value just calculate nominator and denominator seperately and then perform the division. This way intermediate errors do not occur. If not you need to reformulate your question.